# Adding Site Collection Owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, csom, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to add an account to the site collection owners on users personal sites. I'm using the following:

```
User spUser = null;
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL)) {
    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    if (clientContext != null)
    {
        spUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(userAccount);
        spUser.IsSiteAdmin = true;
        spUser.Update();

        clientContext.Load(spUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

> You need to be a site collection administrator to set this property.

On the Sharepoint site, the user is under site collection Administrators.

I'm also looking to do this from a console application.

Answer (score 1):

The error `You need to be a site collection administrator to set this property` occurs when one of the following conditions does not met:

- Ensure the user performing a request is a `Site Collection Administrator`
- Ensure permissions for the App, explicitly request `FullControl` permission at the `Site Collection` scope as shown below:

[image]

Follow [Adding Site Collection Admin in CSOM in a SharePoint 2013 App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2014/01/22/adding-site-collection-admin-in-csom-in-a-sharepoint-2013-app.aspx) article for a more details.

Comment: I'm using a console app to apply the permissions and trying to apply to sharepoint online. I'm hoping to then use this code in powershell